# Update MySQL Row only if it needs to

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I have a webhook from Stripe for changing a users email address.

I wanted to make it possible to change it on the Stripe website and have it carry over to my site and vice versa.

**How it goes now is:**
User changes email on site, site updates the email in mysql, send info to Stripe, Stripe initiates webhook, webhook updates the email again for no reason.

The way I was thinking about solving this is to have the webhook mysql query only update the email again if the value is actually going to change (aka, only if I update the email through the Stripe dashboard).

Does anyone know how I can turn this query into something that only runs if the email is different?

```
$update_email = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `email` = :email WHERE id = :id");
$update_email->execute(array(
    ':email'   => $new_email,
    ':id'   => $user_id,
));
```

I'm also open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: I think that's the default behavior

Comment: Although what you try to do is correct and I would probably try to do it as well, how many queries do you think you will save the server from doing per month / year?

Comment: As @Fabricator says, that's what you're already doing. Besides, adding a separate step to check if the data needs updating would actually increase the load on the database server, not decrease it.

Comment: @jeroen this is kind of my "issue" with every webhook instance. Updating user, deleting a card, etc. I doubt it would cause a huge issue I just know there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

You could read the email first before trying to update to determine if that will change the value, which is a cheaper operation than an update. There is a race condition that the value has changed to the one you are looking for between you reading and updating. Regardless, I'm not sure how much you buy in performance for an update that's happening based on a primary key.

One optimization open to you, however, is making the update conditional on the email value, i.e.

```
$update_email = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `email` = :email WHERE id = :id AND email <> :email");
$update_email->execute(array(
    ':email' => $new_email,
    ':id'    => $user_id,
));
```

This will at least prevent the overwriting of an identical value (although the optimizer might do this for you regardless).